# How could i redirect a user to a specific primary key

Tags: python, django

Good evening everyone,
I am writing a forum where there are different rooms, in each room a user can leave a comment and also update it as needed.
After updating the comment, i want to redirect the user to the same room where this comment was.
I tried:

1.Reverse + HTTPResponseRedirect

urls

```
urlpatterns = [

path('login/', views.loginPage, name="login"),
path('logout/', views.logoutUser, name="logout"),
path('register/', views.registerPage, name="register"),
path('', views.home, name="home"),
path('room/<str:pk>/', views.room, name="room"),
path('profile/<str:pk>/', views.userProfile, name="user-profile"),
path('create-room/', views.createRoom, name="create-room"),
path('update-room/<str:pk>/', views.updateRoom, name="update-room"),
path('delete-room/<str:pk>/', views.deleteRoom, name="delete-room"),
path('delete-message/<str:pk>/', views.deleteMessage, name="delete-message"),
path('update-message/<str:pk>/', views.updateMessage, name="update-message"),

]
```

views

```
def room(request, pk):
    room = Room.objects.get(id=pk)
    room_messages = room.message_set.all().order_by('created')
    participants = room.participants.all()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        message = Message.objects.create(
            user=request.user,
            room=room,
            body=request.POST.get('body')
        )
        room.participants.add(request.user)
        return redirect('room', pk=room.id)

    context = {'room': room, 'room_messages': room_messages,
               'participants': participants,}
    return render(request, 'base/room.html', context)



@login_required(login_url='login')
def updateMessage(request, pk):
    message = Message.objects.get(id=pk)
    form = MessageForm(instance=message)
    if request.user != message.user:
        return HttpResponse('Unable to edit message')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MessageForm(request.POST, instance=message)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(
                reverse(
                    "room",
                    kwargs={
                        "pk": "13"
                    }
                )
                
            )
            
    return render(request, 'base/message_form.html',{'obj':message, 'form': form})
```

but it's working  out to return the user only when I manually write the id of the room in which the comment is. Is there a way to bind the id of the comment and the id of the room?
I tried to search for similar material and looked for similar projects on github repos, but I can't figure out how to do it, the only thing I understand is that I need somehow to link two primary keys and I don't know if I'm moving in the right direction
Thank you for your attention

Comment: Can we see your `urlpatterns` inside of `urls.py`

Comment: Yes, i just edited the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are halfway there.

You have used the ORM to get the message, but you aren't utilizing it to generate the URL for redirection. You can do something like this:

```py
reverse('room', kwargs={'pk': str(message.pk)})
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your time, i get this. 
DoesNotExist at /room/18/
Room matching query does not exist.

The message id was 18, and now it passed it as room parameter id.

So room id = 12
message id = 18

after implementing it just equalize message id to room id

Comment: Assuming that a message already has a foreignkey to a room, you could do `message.room.pk`

Comment: coderman1234, muchos gracias, i was struggling a lot and your answer made me rethink, i wish i had a mentor like you

Comment: As they say, de nada.

Comment: By the way, if you are all done with this question, mark this answer as correct so that others won't get confused